# Intent extra does not send the right result

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

The below example is taken from chapter 10 of BigNerdRanch Android book. 
When my crime list fragment starts a crime fragment then the id that is retrieved through the extra is not the same as in crime list fragment. This produces a null pointer exception.  Also, in the crimelab, I have a log in the if condition but that never gets logged meaning the if condition never gets true. Can somebody please help me with this.

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {
..
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Crime c= ((CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimeActivity.class);
        Log.d(TAG, c.getmTitle() + " " + c.getmId());
        i.putExtra(CrimeFragment.EXTRA_CRIME_ID, c.getmId());
        startActivity(i);
    }
..
}

public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
..
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UUID crimeId = (UUID)getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
                //mCrime = new Crime();
        Log.d(TAG, CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId).getmTitle());
        df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    }
..
}

public class CrimeLab {
.. 
       public Crime getCrime(UUID id){
        for (Crime c:mCrimes){          
            if (c.getmId() == id)
                Log.d(TAG, c.getmTitle());
                return c;
        }
        return null;

    }
..
}
```

> 03-14 18:30:33.649: D/CrimeListFragment(2162): Crime # 2
>   0bf14f8e-8527-4eae-a5a0-c8a19709a4df 03-14 18:30:33.729:
>   D/CrimeFragment(2162): Crime # 0

Comment: What data type does `getmId()` return? You probably just need to use `getStringExtra()` or `getIntExtra()`.

Comment: Its UUID, thats why serialazable

Comment: Oops, yeah. Sorry. I should've seen that. Not sure about the Intent extra, but in your if conditional, I think you should use `equals()` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem and spend may hours to fix it but now its start to work after fixing some silly mistake
try to compare the methods

> public void onListItemClick(ListView l ,View v,int position, long id)
>       {
>           //Crime c =(Crime)(getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
>           Crime c=((CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
>           //Log.d(TAG, c.getTitle() + " Was Clicked");
>
> ```
>     //Start Crime Activity
>    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),CrimeActivity.class);
>    i.putExtra(CrimeFragment.EXTRA_CRIME_ID,c.getId());
>    startActivity(i);
>
> }
> ```
>
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>       {
>
> ```
>    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>   //mCrime = new Crime();
>   UUID crimeId = (UUID)getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
>   //UUID crimeId = (UUID)getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
>  mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> public Crime getCrime(UUID id) {
>           for (Crime c:mCrimes){
>               if (c.getId().equals(id))
>                   return  c;
>           }
>       return  null;
>       }